# The v8 Routing API does not seem to have Isoline - is it being removed?

Tags: here-api

[Routing v7 API](https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/dev_guide/topics/resource-calculate-isoline.html) is available to construct an Isoline from a given location, but I notice [v8 API](https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing-api/8.6.4/api-reference-swagger.html) doesn't seem to mention this feature at all. Is it just not in yet? Or is it not expected to be supported after v7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Isoline Routing feature will be available in the Routing API v8 very soon. Follow our [developer blog](https://developer.here.com/blog) for an announcement when it is out.